# Let a cyclic group $A=\langle a\rangle$ act on a group $G$ whose order is odd. If $[G,a^2]=1$, then $\{x\in G: x=x^{-a}\}=\{[x,a]:x\in G\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, cyclic-groups

> Let a cyclic group $A=\langle a\rangle$ act on a group $G$ whose order is odd. If $[G,a^2]=1$, then $$\{x\in G: x=x^{-a}\}=\{[x,a]:x\in G\}.$$

**My attempt:** Since $[G,a^2]=1$, so $x^{a^2}=x$ for all $x\in G$. Therefore,
$$[x,a]^a=(x^{-1}x^{a})^a=x^{-a}x^{a^2}=x^{-a}x=[x,a]^{-1}$$ for all $x\in G$. Thus, $$\{x\in G: x=x^{-a}\}\supseteq \{[x,a]:x\in G\}.$$

---

How do I show the other inclusion? I know that the cardinality of $\{[x,a]:x\in G\}$ is equal to $[G:C_G(a)]$, so if I can show the same for $\{x\in G: x=x^{-a}\}$, then I would be done. However, I'm not sure how to count the elements of this set.

Comment: What's $x^a$?  The notation has me confused.

Comment: I believe it is the result of $a$ acting on  $x$, @Cpc.

Comment: @Shaun that makes sense.   I've seen it before.   But then how do you do the commutator $[x,a]$?  (It's probably just me.)

Comment: @Cpc $[x,a]=x^{-1}x^a$.

Comment: How do you get that?  It seems like $x^a$ has two different meanings here.

Comment: @Cpc That's the definition of $[x,a]$ and $x^a$ has only one meaning, the result of $a$ acting on $x$.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: you might think $x^a$ means $a^{-1}xa$ but that doesn't really make sense because apriori we haven't defined a product of elements of the two groups $A$ and $G$. However, if you view $A$ and $G$ inside the semidirect product $G \rtimes A$, then conjugation of $x \in G$ with $a \in A$ equals $a^{-1}xa = x^a$. This is where the definition of the "commutator" $[x, a]$ comes from.

Comment: @Sverre Right, and these notations are of Kurzweil and Stellmacher, not mine. I don't know why I'm getting downvoted.